# Pythonic way to loop through dictionary and perform conditional GET request

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

Suppose we have a simple dictionary where each value is a string.

`my_dict = {"A": "Good", "B": "Bad", "C": "Good"}`

Then, for each entry in the dictionary where the value meets some criteria, e.g, `== "Good"`, we wish to perform a GET request using the `get()` method in the `requests` library.

Each GET request will ping a different URL, which would be connected to the key, e.g., `https://our_endpoint.com/KEY`. The output from each endpoint would be a list of values and we would want to ultimately have a single list containing all values from qualifying endpoints.

For performance, I would only like to make a GET request when necessary.

My current method is as follows:

```
output = []
for key in my_dict.keys():
    if my_dict[key] == "Good":
        # GET request to a particular URL
        # extract some data as a list
        output += extracted_list
```

Is there a more Pythonic solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use items:

```
output = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if value == "Good":
        # GET request to a particular URL
        # extract some data as a list
        output += extracted_list
```

Comment: Great suggestion. Makes sense and small change. Don’t see any way of avoiding looping through all items and checking the condition?

Comment: @JonS. That's write.  This is as succinct as you can make it.  Please go ahead and accept my answer if you like it.

Answer (score 3):

```
output = []
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    if v == "Good":
        requests.get(url + k)
        # extract some data as a list
        output.append(extracted_list)
```

Comment: Note that appending a list to a list will make a list of lists. Not clear in my question, which is why I use +=